# How to handle attributes with lists as entries in an prediction/regression models?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-mining

I'm working on a prediction model for the music industry. For this I have a database filled with data about a lot of songs. E.g. the name, producer or artists.
My Problem is, that there are a lot of data with lists as entries. For example, there are a lot of songs with more than one artist.

I could split this entries, so that I have multiple columns for artists, but I am not sure how to handle all the empty rows. When one song has 5 Artists listed, but the majority of songs only one, the majority would have four empty columns.

Is this the best way to handle this? I thought about restricting all songs to one Artists only, but the Artists names are sorted alphabetically, so I have the risk to remove the mega star from the song, which would probably made my prediction invalid.

So what's the best way to handle empty rows, because of data point which can have 1:n entries?

Answer (score 0):

Represent the data as a graph, not as a single table.

Any suitable approach will need to allow n:m connections, so you can either use multiple tables (without using the same unique key everywhere, obviously, or simply as a graph. I.e.

```
| Song 1 | Artist 1 |
| Song 1 | Artist 2 |
| Song 2 | Artist 3 |
```

Etc. - very classic link table in SQL databases, with two foreign keys.